# Any way to re-evaluate the dynamic action logic after a dynamic action has changed the record?

Tags: quickaction, lightning-quickaction, flexipages, dynamic-actions

It is now possible to have action buttons rendered in the "Highlights Panel" depending on field values in the record - [dynamic actions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lex_dynamic_actions_highlights_panel.htm&type=5&release=228) - and this works nicely in general.

But it appears that the evaluation is only done when the page first loads, so if one of the actions modifies a record field, the set of buttons shown does not change. My example below is toggling a checkbox on the record and it would be great to swap the button from "On" to "Off" or "Off to "On" to show the state. The button change only appears when the page is refreshed.

Is there a way to make the buttons change when the record is updated by one of the actions?

[image: dynamic action example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I've added a "Settings..." button that is a `ScreenAction` action where its dialog box includes a checkbox to do the on/off switch.

Harder for users to find and extra clicks but will do I guess as a work-around.

(Would be great if there is a way to do the re-evaluation, so if you find out there is, do post the answer here, and I will gladly make that the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]);` which refresh standard components as well as re-evaluate dynamic actions conditions

[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_modules.htm&type=5&release=228)